# Excel value listing and dating in 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As you can see, I have the dates in first row, the code numbers for a specific item in first column, and the values corresponding to items withdrawn from the inventory. Those are usually -1 but could be anything

[image: Value grid with dates and codes]

What is needed is that whenever a new value is entered, say tomorrow 11-Jan, for items with code '3' and '6', I want the code and the date it was entered to appear on the next sheet.

[image: Date and code listing]

Problem is:

The dates and codes should appear on a compact list, without empty cells interfering. For example, if I take and item on 13-Jan , I want that date and its code to come up on the cell just under the (11-Jan , 6 ).

I'm stuck in how to make it remember the date of an entry, and keep it unchangeable with a formula. Also, how to retrieve the corresponding codes and the entries, and list them all in a column, without empty cells interfering on the list?

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have an unpivot data requirement, and thanks to [this handy youtube video](https://youtu.be/K4tB8JJ-0Wc?si=Jp6I_CbSN9xzDlj3), there's a complex formula available here that only requires three parameters. Based on your image swap these addresses in for variables:

- `dataRng` = `b2:x17` (or wherever the last potential data point is
- `rowAxis` = `A2:A17`
- `colAxis` = `B1:x1`

The forward is below, but it won't give you a clean list, and you'll have to...

- Filtering out blank values
- Dropp column 3 as you don't actually need volumes
- Sort by first column (optional)
- Display headers (if needed)

So your final result would be as shown below. Again, the variables/sheet may be wrong, but it works.

```
=LET(allData, LET(dataRng,Sheet1!B2:X17, rowAxis, Sheet1!A2:A17, colAxis,Sheet1!B1:X1,
          amountCol,   TOCOL(dataRng),
          iCol,                  COLUMN(INDEX(rowAxis,1,1)),
          rAxis,  INDEX(rowAxis,
                             INT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(amountCol),1,0,1)/COLUMNS(dataRng))+1,
                             BYCOL(INDEX(rowAxis,1,),
                                               LAMBDA(eachColumn,
                                                     COLUMN(eachColumn) -iCol +1))),
           yAxis,    INDEX(colAxis,
                               SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(colAxis),1,1),
                               MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(amountCol),1,0,1),COLUMNS(dataRng))+1),
        HSTACK(rAxis,yAxis,amountCol)),
cleanData,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(allData,2,1),CHOOSECOLS(allData,3)<>""),VSTACK(HSTACK("Date","Code"),cleanData))
```

[image: so your final formula in a more cleaned up state would be]

Answer (score 0):

Using Office 365 you could use:

`=LET(m,B2:X17<>"",SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(B1:X1/m,2),TOCOL(A2:A17/m,2))))`

This works for both values and strings in `B2:X17`
it first creates an array `m` of boolean for `B2:X17<>""` this is used to create an array of the header values `B1:X1` divided by `m`. If `m` is `TRUE` it means header value divided by `1` (equals the header value), if `FALSE` it means divided by `0` (resulting in an error).
`TOCOL` flattens the array and the second argument `2` filters out any errors, leaving only the headers where `m` equals `TRUE`.

Same logic is used for the code values `A2:A17`.

The two TOCOL-arrays are stacked and sorted, so it starts with the youngest date.

You could also choose to add the headers:
`=LET(m,B2:X17<>"",VSTACK({"Date","Code"},SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(B1:X1/m,2),TOCOL(A2:A17/m,2)))))`

If your data size change often you could choose to declare the data (including headers):

```
=LET(data, A1:X17,
     m,    DROP(data,1,1<>"",
VSTACK({"Date","Code"},SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(DROP(TAKE(data,1),,1)/m,2),TOCOL(DROP(TAKE(data,,1),1)/m,2)))))
```

that way you only need to change the data range  `A1:X17` for the formula to adopt.